# How to validate content for a forumpost for own PDO database-class ? (to prevent SQL Injections)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, validation, pdo

I am still working on my own database class with pdo:

```
class Database {

    private $databaseConnection;

    public function __construct($path = "", $dbUsername = "", $dbPassword = ""){
        $parts = explode('.',$path);
        $documentType = array_pop($parts);

        if(($path == "") || ((strcmp($documentType, "sq3") !== 0) && (strcmp($documentType, "sqlite") !== 0))) {
            throw new OwnException("The Database must bee .sq3 or .sqlite and Path must be stated");
        }

        $this->databaseConnection = new PDO('sqlite:' . $path, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
        $this->databaseConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->databaseConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $this->databaseConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

        self::query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User(
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                username VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                numberoflogins INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
                bannedstatus BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
                dateofjoining TIME
            )');//password field coming soon

        //self::query('CREATE TABLE...');

        //self::query('CREATE TABLE...');
    }

    private function query($sql, $params = NULL){
        $pdoStatement = $this->databaseConnection->prepare($sql);
        $pdoStatement->execute(array_values((array) $params));
        return $pdoStatement;
    }

    public function getObjects($objectTable, $searchedForAttribute, $attributeValue){
        $pdoStatement = $this->databaseConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM $objectTable  WHERE  $searchedForAttribute = ?");
        $pdoStatement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, $objectTable);
        $pdoStatement->execute(array($attributeValue));
        $resultObjects = array();
        while($resultObject = $pdoStatement->fetch()){
            array_push($resultObjects, $resultObject);
        }
        if(empty($resultObjects)){
            return false;
        }
        return $resultObjects; 
    }

    public function getObject($objectTable, $searchedForAttribute, $attributeValue){
        //...returns only the first Object from getObjects()
    }

    public function insertObject($object){
    $objectTable = get_class($object);
        $objectData = $object->getAttributes();
        return $this->query("INSERT INTO $objectTable("
               . join(',', array_keys($objectData)) . ")VALUES(" 
               . str_repeat('?,', count($objectData)-1). '?)', $objectData);
    }

    public function updateAttribute($objectTable, $setData, $searchedAttribute, $searchedAttributeValue){
    ...
    }

    public function updateObject($object){
    ...
    }

    public function attributeRemoveObject($objectTable, $searchedForAttribute, $attributeValue){
    ...
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        unset($this->databaseConnection);
    }
}
```

as you can see there is still no data validation for the functions (and no exception handling, work in progress) such like getObjects() so the variables $objectTable, $searchedForAttribute and $attributeValue going direct into the query. This means no protection against SQL injections.

So I thought it would be quite helpful if I use a static function to validate data before inserting into query:

```
public static function validate($unsafeData){
    //validate $unsafeData
    return $safeData
    }
```

Because I want to have the ability to search for usernames with similar names and stuff bin2hex() and hex2bin() is a bad choice and for some attributes like the username it is easy to find some starting points for the validation. For instance I would search for empty space, ', " and =...

But how should I validate the content of a forumpost which contains a lot of signs used for SQL queries to? I mean it could also be a a post about sql itself.

I saw a lot of examples for SQL Injections but all of them missing the point that the main manipulation could also be in the content box.

So how does a forum prevent SQL Injections and Errors referring to the content of a post ?

Comment: Parameterized/Prepared queries will avoid SQL injection.

Comment: ehm... No: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your weakest point is here:

```
public function insertObject($object){
    $objectTable = get_class($object);
        $objectData = $object->getAttributes();
        return $this->query("INSERT INTO $objectTable("
               . join(',', array_keys($objectData)) . ")VALUES(" 
               . str_repeat('?,', count($objectData)-1). '?)', $objectData);
    }
```

The best way to avoid SQL injection is using [PDO::bindParam](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php). It **doesn't matter** if a string field contains valid SQL as long as you use prepared queries and bound parameters:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$pquery = $pdo->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO table(column1, column2) VALUES(:column1, :column2)');

// PDO::PARAM_INT, PDO::PARAM_STR, PDO::PARAM_BOOL, etc.
$pquery->bindValue(':column1', $column1, PDO::PARAM_INT); // error if $column1 isn't integer value
$pquery->bindValue(':column2', $column2, PDO::PARAM_STR); // string are sanitized
$pquery->execute();
```

For an arbitrary object you have to use some sort of metadata to select the correct `PDO::PARAM_X` value (default is `PDO::PARAM_STR`):

```
<?php

class User
{
    public $username = 'foo\'; DROP TABLE User; --';
    public $email    = 'bar@gmail.com';
    public $age      = 500;
}

function getColumnType()
{
    return PDO::PARAM_STR; // just for demo
}

$object = new User;

$ref = new ReflectionObject($object);
$table = $ref->getShortName(); // to avoid FQN
$properties = $ref->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);

$params  = []; $columns = [];
foreach ($properties as $property) {
    $params[]  = ':'.($columns[] = $property->getName());
}

// in memory db for demo
$pdo = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->exec('create table User(id INTEGER PRIMARY_KEY, username VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,email VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,age INT)');

// your answer
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$pquery = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO $table(".implode(',', $columns).") VALUES(".implode(',', $params).")");

foreach ($properties as $property) {
    $paramName = ':'.$property->getName();
    $paramValue = $property->getValue($object);
    $paramType = getColumnType($object, $property); // return PDO::PARAM_X
    $pquery->bindValue($paramName, $paramValue, $paramType);
}

$pquery->execute();

// check
$all = $pdo->prepare('select * from User');
$all->execute();
var_dump($all->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User'));
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  class User#10 (4) {
    public $id =>
    NULL
    public $username =>
    string(25) "foo'; DROP TABLE User; --"
    public $email =>
    string(13) "bar@gmail.com"
    public $age =>
    string(3) "500"
  }
}
```

You must implement `getColumnType` to get the correct column data type, for example, parsing annotated comments. But at this point you better use some ORM like **Eloquent** or **Doctrine**.